# List of tags with links

Tags: wordpress, filter, hyperlink, tags, polylang

How can I get a list of Wordpress tags with their links, in alphabetical order. There should be a filter to show tags that are only in English language (using Polylang as a language switcher).

Would appreciate all help!

I have tried copy-pasting some codes, but it did not help.